# I want to make witty comments, but I don't know if I used the tenses correctly or not

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

Should I use present perfect or simple past in the sentences below?

1. > Every man wants sex. If he doesn't, he just **experienced** it.
   >   Every man wants sex. If he doesn't, he **has just experienced** it.
2. > Nine out of ten men want sex. The one who doesn't just **experienced** it.
   >   Nine out of ten men want sex. The one who doesn't **has just experienced** it.

By the way, the jokes are not to be offensive. If they offended you, please forgive me.

Comment: All the sentences are fine.  On a different level: they're not funny, though. I don't mean they're offensive or bad; they're not. They just lack the suprise-value/oomph of humor.

Comment: You say you want to make 'witty' comments, but you did not show any in your question.

Comment: The joke probably works in your native language, but less so in English. I'm not even sure what the punchline is, to tell you the truth. How does someone "experience" sex? You "have" or "do" sex, sometimes we say "make love" as a more romantic equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the subject matter is quite bawdy, the use of "just experienced it" is far too formal. The end of a joke is called a 'punchline' because it is meant to be 'punchy', and have an immediate impact. The shorter the better.

How about:

> Nine out of ten men want sex. The one who doesn't just had it.

(or a more colloquial term like "got some").

Comment: "Every man wants sex. If he doesn't, he's just had it." This is potentially funny, since "had it" can mean "died".

Comment: This sounds funnier indeed. The word "had" is the word that often comes before "sex", and this makes the sentence more colloquial, and in your words, punch harder.